# Phonegap Android LocalFileSystem is not defined

Tags: android, cordova

I have a problem for accessing Android File System for storage purpose in my phonegap application. I've searched and found lots of not-my-situation solutions!

I know about the necessity of deviceready to be fired and checked and it got fired. So the phonegap.js is loaded perfectly!

I think I requested the file permissions and have features in my manifest and config file. here they are:

config.xml:

```
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <content src="index.html" />
</widget>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.pakhshyaran.kara" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission." />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Kara" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
</manifest>
```

and here is the error throwing part of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) { //throws the 'Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined' error
        fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }, function (evt) {
        alert(evt.target.error.code);
    });
}
```

But I get the error for a reason I don't have any idea about! Please give me your thought. I appreciate it very much.

PS: I'm using phonegap 3.0!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you using phonegap cli to build your project? Then you might have missed adding the File plugin to your project. Besides configuring in `config.xml` and `AndroidManifiest.xml` you need the code for the plugin. You can add it to your project with:

```
$ phonegap plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

Check top of page in the docs: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem

You can also check the file `android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js` to see if `window.LocalFileSystem` is actually defined. Look for somthing like this:

```
{
    "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.core.file/www/FileSystem.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.core.file.FileSystem",
    "clobbers": [
        "window.FileSystem"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't know that I have to add the plugin. I run the command and it got executed. but nothing happend to the cordova_plugins.js. Is there something else I should know?

Comment: @Hosein Adding the plugin actually adds the configuration as well. Try building it again: cordova build android

Comment: Installing a plugin has 2 parts: 1) you install the plugin with CLI: "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" - this will update AndroidManifest.xml and res/xml/config.xml. 2) You do "cordova build android" - this writes the neccessary JS plugin files to www/plugins.