# Getting error while adding phonegap LocalFileSystem plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to add LocalFileSystem plugin into my project. But when i execute this command phonegap plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git from '../assets/www/' directory i get this error : JScript runtime error 800A1391 'window' is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using phonegap 3.0. I updated phonegap to latest version 3.4 and that solved my problem. The .cordova folder was not present in my project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're in the right directory, you want to be in the root of your Cordova/PhoneGap application (where the config.xml is located). For you, it looks like it might be your /assets/ directory. Also, try this command:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file`

Taken from: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file

Comment: my config.xml is in C:\MyDrive\GENERIX\PROJECTS\i-Reflect\i-reflect\i-reflect-android\app\src\main\res\xml. But i'm getting same error in this location.

Comment: what version of PhoneGap are you using? How did you first create the PhoneGap project, was it just copied from somewhere else or did you use `cordova create ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the main folder of your project (The highest level folder) and execute

`cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git`

at the CLI.  You also need to configure config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml according to the docs: [Phonegap Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem)

See [phonegap-android-localfilesystem-is-not-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683253/phonegap-android-localfilesystem-is-not-defined)