# Cordova file plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm using `cordova 5.1.1` in my project. I have in the `cordova_plugins.js` the declaration of the file plugin:

```
{
    "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileSystem.js",
    "id": "cordova-plugin-file.FileSystem",
    "clobbers": [
        "window.FileSystem"
    ]
},
```

But when I try to use the plugin like this:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
```

I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined
```

Comment: Duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683253/phonegap-android-localfilesystem-is-not-defined

Comment: no I have installed the file plugin successfully and I had the declaration of the plugin on cordova_plugins.js. Their solution have no relation with my problem

Answer (score 0):

No response listener so the file plugin isn't loaded that's why you get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined
```

Add this and include your request inside it:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() { 
  //use request file here
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}, false);
```

Comment: It works but with the :`filesystem.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail1);`  I get :`Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalMediaDirs, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.file.LocalFilesystem.isPublicDirectory`